# How to send a file using POST method to TelegramBot?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, telegram-bot

I want to send a file with the post method, but I don't know what's wrong with my code
I have chat_id, file_id, and every requirement parameters
this is a sample code for sending voice via POST Request

```
import requests

my_data = {'chat_id': '72600457' ,'file_id': 'AwADBAADPAYAAvFWCVFZFfPyZdGLfhYE'}
my_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY TOKEN>/sendVoice'
request.post(url=my_url, data=my_data)
```

when I run the code, no error happens. But nothing is shown from the bot;
This file_id works with GET METHOD and I could send text with POST METHOD, But for files it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to show what you did for others to find the problem.

Comment: @Mohammed I could send a text via the POST method, but I couldn't send any file

Comment: check documentation for [sendVoice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvoice). It doesn't uses `file_id` but `'voice': 'AwADBAADPAYAAvFWCVFZFfPyZdGLfhYE'`. BTW: if you use ID of file then you can use `get(my_url, params=my_data)`. And next time you should display response from server to see information about wrong request - `response = requests.post(...)`  `print(response.json())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation for [sendVoice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvoice) - it doesn't use name `file_id` but `voice`

```
data = {'chat_id': '72600457', 'voice': 'AwADBAADPAYAAvFWCVFZFfPyZdGLfhYE'}
```

If you use file ID then you can use `POST` but also `GET`

And you should get response from server to see information about wrong request

```
import requests

token = '<MY TOKEN>'

data = {'chat_id': '72600457', 'voice': 'AwADBAADPAYAAvFWCVFZFfPyZdGLfhYE'}
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendVoice'

#response = requests.post(url, data=data)
response = requests.get(url, params=data)

print(response.json())
```

---

By the way: there is module [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/). GitHub: [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)